# Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: update, 8.1

I have a HTC Windows Phone 8S and I still don't have the update for Windows Phone 8.1. Am I the only one or is it not available for my phone? :s

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to get it like everybody else! (However, please note, it’s a preview not an official update).

Basically you need to:

1. Register as a developer (there is a free of charge option).
2. Install the “[Preview for Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96)” app.

Follow the full instructions [here](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/get-windows-phone-81-soon-possible).
Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Hi Itai. Instead of merely linking to the instructions, please pose the skeleton here so that if the external link ever dies, you answer doesn't become irrelevant

Comment: And if the official comes out, could I still download it if I have the one for developers?

Comment: You won't need to since the "one for developers" is actually the final bits to be released. so as for your question... yes